# Run Laravel Dusk from schedule (cron)

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I need run Laravel (5.6.13) Dusk test with cron.

I have setuped schedule, but it does not work.

There is no errors or some information in logs. Maybe is incorrect settings?

When ruan manually from console, everything works fine.

\app\Console\Kernel.php:

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('dusk tests/Browser/ProductComment.php')->everyFifteenMinutes();
    }

    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know it does not work? Do you get an error or something?

Comment: Why do you want to run a test every 15 minutes?

Comment: @TheFallen> All tests have log system, inserts the information (start and ends time) to the database.

Comment: You should save the output of the execution with `->sendOutputTo('file.log')` to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You must execute directly with php

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->exec('php ' . base_path('artisan') . ' dusk')->everyFifteenMinutes();
}
```